# load java x86_64 jnilib on i386 Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, x86-64

I have a MAC OS 10.5.8 on i386 architecture and jvm1.6.0_26 64-Bits

I've started the JVM with java.library.path=lewys/macosx/x86_64 and i have:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: .../macosx/x86_64/libLeWYS.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  .../macosx/x86_64/libLeWYS.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1742)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at org.objectweb.lewys.probe.macosx.CpuProbe.<clinit>(CpuProbe.java:58)
    at org.ow2.clif.probe.cpu.Insert.<init>(Insert.java:72)
    ... 55 more
```

It there a workaround ?

Thanks

PS: Forcing the 32 bit data model does not work, ex: java -d32 says Cannot run Java in 32 bit mode, Continuing in 64 bit mode

Comment: You are running a 64-bit JVM on a 32-bit architecture? Hmm...

Comment: Yes as i said i cannot run a 1.6jvm in 32 bits mode.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?
There is no reason to run a 64bit VM on 32bit Windows. The only reason I could think of is that a VM is shipped with a VM included. And that is a practice for which vendors should be put up against a wall and shot.

Comment: Can't you install a 32-bit JVM instead? There seems to be a port for 32-bit Java 6 on MacOS 10.5.x: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/

Comment: @owlstead He's not running on Windows :), btw: http://www.flickr.com/photos/jordoncooper/410912420/ :D

Comment: Whoops, sorry. But it does not matter much regarding the answer - fortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that as the native libs within the JVM are for x86-64 bit only.

If you are running on a 64 bit CPU with virtualization extensions, then you *could* run it in a virtual machine though, because you would be back into a 64 bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can force 32 bit in Eclipse by passing a '-d32' as a VM argument:
[image: Forcing 32 bit]

This is working for me with JVM 1.6.0_51 64 Bit on OSX 10.8.4

I was receiving the same compile error and this fixed it.